# Vergebens oder vergeblich?

Tags: vocabulary, synonym

In Schillers Drama *Die Jungfrau von Orleans* steht die Zeile:

> Mit der Dummheit kämpfen die Götter selbst vergebens.

Ich finde dieses Zitat sehr angebracht, aber ich kann mich nicht daran erinnern, ob das Adverb *vergebens* oder *vergeblich* lauten muss (im Originaltext steht, wie oben wiedergegeben, *vergebens*).

Gibt es heutzutage zwischen diesen Adverbien eine Nuance? Gab es eine zu Schillers Zeit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"[Vergeblich](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/vergeblich)" ist ein Adjektiv, "[vergebens](https://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/vergebens)" ein Adverb. Insofern ist der Satz

> Mit der Dummheit kämpfen die Götter selbst vergeblich

falsch. Allerdings hat sich der heutige Sprachgebrauch über diese Unterscheidung hinweggesetzt. M.E. wird "vergebens" nicht mehr oft verwendet.

Comment: Danke, Paul: Ihre Erklärung ist einfacher als ich vermutete. (Aber: was bedeutet M.E. ?)  Und ich freue mich, dass wir gemeinsame Interessen haben: Deutsch, Russisch und Mathematik!

Comment: Aber Adjektive können doch ohne weiteres adverbial gebraucht werden? *Können Sie mich gut hören*?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg "m.E." steht für "meines Erachtens".  Es fiel mir auch schon auf, dass wir beide auf math.stackexchange.com aktiv sind, bei russian.stackexchange.com war es mir neu. Da bin ich aber eher ein passiver Teilnehmer. Die Kombination Mathematik/Deutsch habe ich übrigens schon öfter bemerkt.

Comment: @David Vogt: Sehr zutreffende Bemerkung! Könnte ein Muttersprachler bestätigen oder widerlegen, dass man heutzutage im Zitat "vergeblich"  (statt des grammatikalisch korrekten "vergebens") schreiben könnte?

Comment: @DavidVogt Das ist richtig, Der Duden führt allerdings "vergebens" und "vergeblich" nicht als Synonyme. Gibt es also doch Unterschiede in der Bedeutung? Allerdings betrachten andere Quellen beide Worte als Synonyme ( https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/vergebens, https://synonyme.woxikon.de/synonyme/vergebens.php, https://www.dwds.de/wb/vergebens). Meine Meinung: Wenn es ein eigenes Adverb wie "vergebens" gibt, sollte man nicht ein Adjektiv adverbial gebrauchen.

Comment: Danke für Ihren reichlich belegten Kommentar, @ Kritiker der Elche  .

Comment: @Björn Friedrich  Danke für Ihre Verbesserung meiner Frage.